# Which Rich Text Editor also paste text and images?

Tags: php, html, rich-text-editor

My friend is making a CMS and we are looking for a Rich Text Editor which works like wordpress's editor.
We have word documents on us which have some text and images on it and we want to make a cms on which we can just copy paste the word and images and it appears on a custom field on our site.
I looked into various editors but it seems they doesn't copy images..
So is there any way that we can also copy images from clipboard to the site?
Or upload the word file and images and content get converted somehow?
Thanks guys for the help.
Really appricate it.

Comment: I think you can use CK editor they have tons of features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out.! Full featured web editing. Featherweight download.

https://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: The free one does not allow image paste :/